# How To Create HTML Form That Accepts Field Values As URL Parameters

Tags: javascript, html

The goal is to create a standalone HTML form that pre-fills fields with text passed as URL parameters.

To test, a plain html file was created with a single textarea named "test". When http://myserver.com/simpleform.html?test=sampletext is typed in the address bar, the text passed as the parameter test does not populate the field.

I thought that the only thing necessary to pre-fill text to a field in a web form was to know the name of the target field. When that failed, I attempted to use some Javascript that would execute on load that I found on another answer provided by Cerbrus here: /a/14070223

But there was no change in the result. When I entered http://myserver.com/simpleform.html#test=sampletext in the address bar, the passed text would not appear in the field. Here is the code I have currently:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload="acceptParam()">

<script>
function acceptParam() {
  var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&'); // substr(1) to remove the `#`
  for(var i = 0; i < hashParams.length; i++){
      var p = hashParams[i].split('=');
      document.getElementById(p[0]).value = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);;
  }
 }
</script>
<center>
<textarea rows="15" name="test" cols="50">

</textarea>
</center>



</body>
</html>
```

Is it even possible to create a web form that accepts field values as URL parameters using a single standalone HTML file? I don't need to submit the data, only to populate the field with text passed in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If url is "http://myserver.com/simpleform.html?test=sampletext", you can do something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload="acceptParam()">
 
<center>
<textarea id='p' rows="15" name="test" cols="50">

</textarea>
</center>


<script>
function acceptParam() {
  var hashParams = window.location.href.substr(1).split('?'); // substr(1) to remove the `#`
      hashParams = hashParams[1].split('&');
      var p = hashParams[0].split('=');
      document.getElementById('p').value = p[1];
 }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I copied the code in this answer in its entirety, and tried both of the following without success:
http://brainflurry.host-ed.me/files/testso.html?test=hello
http://brainflurry.host-ed.me/files/testso.html#test=hello

Comment: @Brainflurry, the code was checking for hash as in question, I have corrected to code using url now, please check again, it should work.

Comment: The Id is `p` here

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Diwas. After modifying the url to pass the parameter to '?p='as @Julian pointed out, it loaded fine. I am accepting this as the answer because it was easiest to understand. It modified the original code to make it work, which through comparison clearly pointed out my error (I failed to declare an id). As an aside, I modified the last line of Javascript to include 'decodeURIComponent()' so that the populated field would display plain text.

Comment: Code was simple, easy to read and effective. Thank you @Dij

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your textarea with the `id` "test" (hence the JavaScript function `getElementById`):

```
<textarea rows="15" id="test" name="test" cols="50">

</textarea>
```

also, you shouldn't use the `<center>` element. It's better to create a parent `div` with the tag `style="text-align:center"` like this :

```
<div style="text-align:center">
<textarea rows="15" id="test" name="test" cols="50">

</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I understood what you meant with the id parameter but I didn't have the expertise to implement the JavaScript to make it all work together. As a beginner, it would have been helpful to see it in the context of the whole script. Thanks again!

Comment: The JS remains the same. You just have to replace the inner body by my html.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the string after `?` with `window.location.search` or the string after `#` with `window.location.hash`.

Rather than parsing and splitting the strings yourself, you can use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to help with that:

```
var queryString = window.location.search;
let params = new URLSearchParams(queryString.substring(1)); // remove the '?'
let value = params.get('test'); // will return the requested parameter
```

Of course, you could then combine this with the loop to get back whichever parameters are provided.

Also note that in your example, you are searching for an element (form field) by `id` but your field only has a `name` and no `id`.

Comment: Warning, `URLSearchParams` isn't supported in IE

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Richard. Your answer led to the valuable insight that URLSearchParams isn't supported in IE. So, thanks to you too @Julian!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it even possible to create a web form that accepts field values as
>   URL parameters using a single standalone HTML file? I don't need to
>   submit the data, only to populate the field with text passed in the
>   URL.

**Sure is.**

Getting data from the query-string (the part after the ? character) and getting the fragment/hash part of the URL are two different things though.

Here's a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload="fetchParams()">

<script>
    function fetchParams()
    {
        document.getElementById('test').value = getQueryStringValue('foo');
        document.getElementById('test2').value = getQueryStringValue('bar');

        // This fetches the data after the hash-character and the value which has 'test' in front of the equals sign:
        //document.getElementById('test').value = getHashParam('test');
    }

    function getQueryStringValue(name)
    {
        var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search.substring(1));
        return params.get(name);
    }

    function getHashParam(name)
    {
        var params = window.location.hash.substring(1).split('&');
        console.log(params);
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++)
        {
            if (params[i].split('=')[0].toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase())
            {
                return params[i].split('=')[1]
            }
        }
    }

</script>

<textarea rows="15" id="test" name="test" cols="50">
</textarea>

<textarea rows="15" id="test2" name="test2" cols="50">
</textarea>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @HaukurHaf. I uploaded your code but still cannot get the passed parameter to populate either of the form fields. See: http://brainflurry.host-ed.me/files/test-HaukurHaf.html?test=sampletext

Comment: It's because my code is actually trying to read values from parameters called foo and bar.  If you want to read from a parameter called test, just add this line here: document.getElementById('test').value = getQueryStringValue('test'); and remove the other two lines in the fetchParams() function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help. I was able to pass a parameter to a standalone HTML page using your code but I accepted the answer by Diwas Joshi because it was easier for me to understand. Diwas' code was closer to my original code which allowed me to more easily see the changes needed to make it work. I didn't fully grasp all of the additional  Javascript in the example code you provided. I'm learning though! Thanks again.